# Universal links & Appsflyer do not work on Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios

We are implementing an email sending automation. We have created universal links to redirect our customer to precise screens in our app. 
These universal links are already working on another platform such as Facebook, IOS email, gmail, Follow analytics except Marketing Cloud.

However, when I try to send a preview to myself (or another people) through Marketing Cloud the link redirects to the AppStore. It should have to redirect to the IOS app to a precise screen.

This is the scheme of our link, we are using universal link for our IOS app thanks to appsflyer :
https://bim.onelink.me/9chh?af_dp=bim://p/355 
==> this link should redirect to the screen of the restaurant named "Dersou" in our app.

Do you have any solutions? Do we have to implement some configurations?

Thanks in advance,

Best Regards,
Damien

---

We have done several tests : 
- We have tried to send an email through Mailchimp with a basic template : it worked. Then we copy the html code from Mailchimp and paste this code in Marketing Cloud and send en email. The universal link did not work.

- We have tried in Marketing Cloud to add a basic https url to link to our website and then redirect to our app through a deeplink and it works.

We can see two things :
1) Appsflyer universal links with appsflyer worked with another email service.
2) When you use a basic https url and then redirect to our app, it works

Therefore :
Appsflyer universal link works with all other platform except Marketing Cloud. It's like the url is wrapped by MC.

Do you know if there is a solution to unwrapped an url on Marketing Cloud ? Or is there something to configure between Appsflyer and Marketing Cloud to make the connection ?

Thanks !

Comment: Some precisions :
- Our app is on IOS.
- We are using Appsflyer for the universal links technology

Comment: If you are using chrome , can you inspect to the page to see the rendered html code?Reason is that when you when you click the link in the question it directs you to app store

Answer (score 1):

When you send the email from Marketing Cloud, your URL endpoint is wrapped/masked as a SAP tracking domain e.g. email.acmecorp.com

This SAP redirects to your endpoint URL. I recall a conversation I had with someone before on this problem - excuse my lack of technicals - but the issue was that Apple wouldn't allow/accept deeplinks that are redirected

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26760

You restriction too is that every SAP link in marketing cloud will be unique to the subscriber, so not possible to register those either.

Comment: My answer to your comment is below